# Add OnClick event for asp.net grid view

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have added new event i.e Gridview_Onclick event dynamically in RowDatabound event. But when I try to handle that event in the server side code, I can code for that event. This is the code for my grid view.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PopUp.ascx.cs" Inherits="PopUp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<table class="style1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptId" HeaderText="ID"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HeadName" HeaderText="HOD"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HeadEmail" HeaderText="Email ID"/>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" style="display:none" />
    </td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

This is the code for my ascs.cs page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    oCommand.CommandText = "select * from Department";
    oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
    oAdapter.SelectCommand = oCommand;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    oAdapter.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(e.Row, string.Empty);
}
protected void GridView1_OnClick(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    _ID = "10";
    _Name = "abc";
    _HOD = "abc";
    _Email = "abc";
}
```

The grid view opens in modelpopupextender so when I click anywhere in grid, its getting closed which is not the case of I remove the event that is added dynamically. In short the event is added but can not be handled in code.
Please guide me how can I catch this event in coding??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do following changes at your code:
1)

```
 e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(**btnTest**, string.Empty);
```

2)

```
 protected void GridView1_OnClick(object sender, **EventArgs** e)
```

3) `<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Style="display: none" **OnClick="GridView1_OnClick"** />`

Why?

The reason is GridViewRow doesn't implement IPostBackEventHandler, therefore doesn''t fire postback events. But button can. At this case btnTest it is dummy button for event firing.

Comment: What is the meaning of ** that you have written??

Comment: I highlighted necessary changes. I thought they'll become bold, but code editor doesn't support it (

Comment: What onclick atribute is rendred for row? <tr onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('btnTest','')"> like this?

Comment: Not getting what you are asking..:(

Comment: Please, open Firebug(or something simmilar) or click View Source in your browser. Your GridView is render to html like this '<table...attributes...><tbody><tr></tr>...<tr></tr></tbody></table>' Every 'tr' tag has onclick attribute. What is value of attribute?

Comment: @ChiragFanse let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2568/discussion-between-icen-and-chirag-fanse)